# Solr return 400 for string field with forward slash

Tags: solr

I am trying to index a JSON document into Solr and for one of the document with a forward slash in the field Solr fails and returns 400.

document in question:

```
[
    {"key": "100", "path": "0"},
    **{"key": "200", "path": "0/6000"}**
]
```

Error:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/ss/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":79},"error":{"msg":"ERROR: [doc=f92efb19-2786-49fd-a8ee-6d1e12fb0cb7] Error adding field 'path'='0/6000' msg=For input string: \"0/6000\"","code":400}}
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/ss/update
1 files indexed.
```

I also tried escaping the "/" in that string, but no luck

Removing that forward slash is working fine. very weird

Comment: What is the field type of "path" in the schema.xml?

Comment: Its String 
<fields>
<field name="path" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
</fields>

<types>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
</types>

Comment: That seems ok. There should be nothing special about adding 0/6000 to a string field, and it works fine when done on test core. However, that value \"0/6000\"" doesn't look right, it has one too many double quotes. Does your input data actually match the data you pasted here?

Comment: the additional double quote is from the Error message itself, I was a bit suspicious about it too, but then that last double quote matches with Error message

Comment: Found the issue. I am using solr 5 and in solr 5, the default schema management is not schema.xml, but its automatically managed by solr. As in previous documents the "path" field is analyzed as long and when it came to "0/6000", solr throws NumberFormatException in server side logs and fails to index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with Solr 5. From version 5, solr by default manages the schema and doesn't read the schema from schema.xml. As indexing starts and "path" field in my documents is a int, solr analyzes it as int, but as it comes to document where "path"="0/6000" it throws NumberFormatException and fails.

For this, you have to make some changes in solrConfig.xml to use schema.xml or stick to solr managing your schema and Solr 5 provides an API to update schema generated by Solr using Schema API (which I ended up using).